When using vscode, how to jump into wanted implement with the same name's functions?
I am using vscode to learn codes of others, and there are several projects in the CmakeList.txt (That is to say, there are several sub projects after the main project, and after building, several executable files will be generated).
But different sub projects contain different files with the same name (like a.cpp) which has functions with the same name (like void func(){}), they are called by those different projects with the similar implement.
But now I want to concertrate in one particular sub project, and when I ctrl + left click on void func(){} to see the implement, all void func(){}s will come out and I have to choose the one that the particular sub project calls.
So how to set my vscode, when I ctrl + left click on void func(){} just jump into my wanted implement?

You can probably open the sub-project in a separate VSCode window, can you not? How would VSCode know which the "correct" implementation is? What if you have an interface class, a base class that inherits from it and an implementation that overloads some functions. If you can only go to the "child" implementation in that hierarchy wouldn't it be pretty annoying to get to the base class' implementation or the interface declaration? I haven't seen a compelling solution for this yet even without subprojects.
